# Angular-chart.js Configuration

Tags: angular, configuration, chart.js

I am in the process of learning Angular (first time using it), but I can't seem to get angular-chart.js working. For some reason my chart is not showing. I installed the packages and followed the documentation. Is there something I am missing here?:

Html file:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app">
    <div id="sidebar">
      <div id="logo">
        <img src="imgs/cloud.png" alt="logo">
      </div>
      <p>{{title}}</p>
    </div>
    <div id="content" ng-controller="DoughnutCtrl">
      <!-- Statistics -->
      <!-- <h1>This is a statement.</h1><br> -->
      <!-- ChartJS Implemenetation -->

        <canvas id="doughnut" class="chart chart-doughnut"
        chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels">
        </canvas>
    </div>
    <script src="../node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="charted.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript file (charted.js):

```
angular.module("app", ["chart.js"])
  .controller('DoughnutCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.labels = ["Download Sales", "In-Store Sales", "Mail-Order Sales"];
    $scope.data = [300, 500, 100];
   }]);
```

Angular-cli.json

```
{
  "project": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta.28.3",
    "name": "soccer-ng"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "app/charted.js",
        "../node_modules/angular/angular.min.js",
        "../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js",
        "../node_modules/angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.min.js"
      ],
      "environments": {
        "source": "environments/environment.ts",
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "files": "src/**/*.ts",
      "project": "src/tsconfig.json"
    },
    {
      "files": "e2e/**/*.ts",
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.json"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "prefixInterfaces": false,
    "inline": {
      "style": false,
      "template": false
    },
    "spec": {
      "class": false,
      "component": true,
      "directive": true,
      "module": false,
      "pipe": true,
      "service": true
    }
  }
}
```

[Graph should show within the pink area...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpqwp.png)

[Error in the console...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZwgH.png)

Just to re-iterate, this is my first time using Angular so it might just be me not understanding a concept or an import. Also if there are any sources that you might recommend for learning Angular it would be appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: Updated to new code... Still not showing.

Comment: Get your facts correct first - Angular ≠ AngularJS

Comment: Thank you, I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the code, couple of issues I see are:

- The module is defined "app" in Javascript, but defined as "examples" in HTML.
- Dont see AngularJS imported in HTML.

I have created a plunker with your code and fixing above issues. Please check:

http://plnkr.co/edit/QHm3kP8HUU6HQjiuQxDW?p=preview

HTML:

```
    <html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app">
    <div id="sidebar">
      <div id="logo">
        <img src="imgs/cloud.png" alt="logo">
      </div>
      <p>{{title}}</p>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
      <!-- Statistics -->
      <h1>This is a statement.</h1><br>
      <!-- ChartJS Implemenetation -->
      <div ng-controller="DoughnutCtrl">
        <canvas id="doughnut" class="chart chart-doughnut"
        chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels">
        </canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-chart.js/1.1.1/angular-chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
    angular.module("app", ["chart.js"]).controller("DoughnutCtrl", function ($scope) {
  $scope.labels = ["Download Sales", "In-Store Sales", "Mail-Order Sales"];
  $scope.data = [300, 500, 100];
});
```

Let me know if you were able to fix from your end.

Comment: what is different from the answer i posted

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have changed what you have listed but it is still not showing. I am currently getting this error in the console:

Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
    at eval (eval at webpackJsonp.667.module.exports (scripts.bundle.js:28), <anonymous>:1:1)

Comment: I updated the code in the original comment, could you check over it and see if you still see any errors? Thank you!

Comment: Sorry. Got a chance to see this only now. Your code looks good. It looks like its a bundling issue. Could you try adding all the scripts used in HTML (angular,chartjs, angular-chart) in the "angular-cli.json" file under "scripts" array were you have already added "app/charted.js".                              "scripts": ["app/charted.js"] - add angular and other vendor libraries as array elements. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Sajeetharan, our responses are the same. Its just that we posted around the same time. :)

Comment: @haca, Let us know if you were able to resolve your issue.

Comment: I tried adding those .js files that are used in the html file to the scripts... however I am still having the same issues. I have updated the code in the original question and posted another screenshot of an error I am getting in the console if that helps. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Got it working, the issue was a combination of what you recommended (adding the .js files to the angular-cli.json) and adding the reference to angular before my other files. Thanks again for the help troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things,

(i) Rename  **`<body ng-app="examples">`** to  **`<body ng-app="app">`**

(ii) You are missing the reference for **`angular.js`**

**DEMO**

```js
angular.module("app", ["chart.js"]).controller("DoughnutCtrl", function ($scope) {
  $scope.labels = ["Download Sales", "In-Store Sales", "Mail-Order Sales"];
  $scope.data = [300, 500, 100];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Multi Slot Transclude</title>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.3.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-chart.js/1.0.3/angular-chart.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="DoughnutCtrl">
  <canvas id="doughnut" class="chart chart-doughnut"
        chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels">
        </canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried editing the code to contain these updates. It is still however not showing the updates. Does anything else look off about it? Thank you for your time!

Comment: check the demo attached! do you see any errors on console

Comment: Your demo works-- I can see the pie chart. There is an error on the console: Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
    at eval (eval at webpackJsonp.667.module.exports (addScript.js:9), <anonymous>:1:1)
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at webpackJsonp.667.module.exports (addScript.js:9)
    at Object.380 (charted.js?851e:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap abb6aaaa0737990afd7a:52)
    at Object.704 (addScript.js:10)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap abb6aaaa0737990afd7a:52)
    at webpackJsonpCallback (bootstrap abb6aaaa0737990afd7a:23)
    at scripts.bundle.js:1

Comment: thats the problem! there is an issue with bundling !

Comment: How would I go about fixing an error with the bundling?

Comment: .controller('DoughnutCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {


}]);

Comment: is that in the js file? I posted the updated code. Still getting the same issues.

Comment: did you sort out this issue?

Comment: I am still having the same issue. I updated my code and added an error that exists in the console if that helps. Thank you.

Comment: The issue ended up being a combination of adding the .js files to the angular-cli.json and adding the reference to angular before my other files. Thank you again for helping out. It is really appreciated.

Comment: Mark as answer if this helped

Answer (score 0):

The issue ended up being a combination of a few factors.

1. Adding the .js files used in the html file in the scripts section.
2. Ordering the angular.min.js file first so it was defined for the other files.

A big thanks everyone who helped me debug this issue. It was really appreciated.